Movie about a planet where seeds must be harvested just right in order to liberate a valuable crystal within
I saw a movie on an airplane sometime between maybe 2016 and 2022 (ballpark). There’s a dangerous faraway planet that people go to for the opportunity to make money. On this planet they grow these weird gooey seed things that, if you harvest them just right, liberate this crystal worth a ton of money. But if you make an error while harvesting (which is easy to do) the plant releases a chemical that destroys the crystal completely, it basically melts.
Things I remember from the movie:

The main character is female
There’s a scene where they meet a guy that is basically keeping a harem in the outlaw planet
There’s a scene where she’s traveling with a guy and he gets a cut, which on this planet will quickly lead to death so they have to very quickly cut off his arm to prevent the infection from killing him
Travel to and from the planet happen infrequently so if you miss the drop you’re stuck for maybe 6 months?
in the end, they steal a ship from some guys trying to plunder the same hoard of these seed things they were headed towards and escape to make the rendezvous

I have googled it like 1000 times with no luck. Any ideas?

This is Prospect (2018).

The film, written and directed by Zeek Earl and Chris Caldwell,
features a teenage girl named Cee (Thatcher) and her father Damon
(Duplass) who land on a poisonous forest moon to mine for valuable
gems. A series of betrayals, alliances, and conflicts with mercenaries
and rival prospectors make their quest increasingly perilous.


The plot synopsis mentions the main character's father getting an infected arm.

Cee retreats to her malfunctioning lander, which won't start, and is
found by Ezra hours later. When Ezra tries to enter, Cee shoots him in
the arm and takes him captive. Ezra proposes following Damon's initial
plan to assist the mercenaries for a ride on their ship. Cee agrees
reluctantly, and they head for the queen's lair. Ezra's arm becomes
infected from the moon's poisonous spores, prompting them to seek
medical help from local villagers. The villagers propose trading gems
for Cee instead. As Ezra inquires about the deal, Cee escapes, pursued
by the villagers.





Yes yes yes 1000 times yes. THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!

@ElFoosballo - As always, you're very welcome
